# Google page speed insights API requiring captcha when using google API credentials

Tags: php, curl, google-api, pagespeed-insights

I'm attempting to hit the PageSpeed Insights API as documented here https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about with PHP and curl and am getting in return a response that looks like this:

```
{
   'captchaResult' => "CAPTCHA_NEEDED"
}
```

My code to query the API looks like this:

```
$url = 'https://google.com';
$cmd = "curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=$url&key={MY_KEY}";
$result = json_decode(`$cmd`, true);
```

The documentation states "If you plan on using the API in an automated way and making multiple queries per second, you'll need an API key". I've created an API key in the developer's console, but am still getting the above result.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to make short bursts of 10-20 requests per second.

I have two questions:

1. Is there any documentation available for rate limiting in the PageSpeed Insights API?
2. How do I satisfy the CAPTCHA_NEEDED requirement for this API?

Answer (score 0):

You required to get the API key to proceed without captcha, via [credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials).

Then set up environment variable with key you got on previous step, for example:

`MY_KEY=adasda5434sdsa234sasdd`

set website url:

`URL="https://EXAMPLE.com"`

then you can use service from CLI:

`curl https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url={$URL}&&key={$MY_KEY}`

Also, you can use curl without variables:

`curl https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://EXAMPLE.com&&key=adasda5434sdsa234sasdd`

Documentation [available](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/reference/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed).